# How to fire a DDL trigger while detaching a database in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: triggers, sql-server-2008-r2, ddl, detach

I know simple ddl triggers like `Create_Table`, `Alter_Table`, `Drop_Table`, I worked with this.

Now I want to know about something like: when a user detaches the database, a trigger should be fired whether the user is valid or not.

```
Create Trigger trgNoNewTables
ON Database
For Create_Table
AS
BEGIN
      Print 'No Tables Please'
      ROLLBACK
END
```

May I know like the above trigger there is any trigger for detach and attach?

Comment: @marc_s by studying the above link only i find those things.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

At best you can create trigger(s) for create/alter/drop database:

```
create trigger foo
on all server
for create_database, drop_database, alter_database
as
print 'triggered!'
go
```

but `sp_detach_db` will not fire it (`sp_attach_db` will).

The proper approach to restrict users from performing actions is security (grant/deny/revoke). Nothing else will work. I suggest you do not grant permissions if users are not allowed to perform an action.

Comment: can you give an example for security(grant/deny/revoke)

Comment: i execute trigger but it is not working. i tried before itself these Create_database ...., i don't get any result i.e., why i post the question.

Comment: [Permissions (Database Engine)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191291.aspx)